# Filtering Nested Arrays in React JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter, nested

I am attempting to filter a list of conversations by participant names. The participant names are properties inside of a participant list and the participant list is contained within a list of conversations.

So far, I have approached the problem by attempting to nest filters:

```
let filteredConvos = this.props.convos.filter((convo) => {
   return convo.conversation.conversation.participant_data.filter(
     (participant) => {
       return participant.fallback_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(
         this.state.searchTerm.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
     })
})
```

This appears to work, insofar as I can confirm (i.e. I put a whole bunch of console.logs throughout an expanded version of the above) that as the `searchTerm` state is updated, it returns matching the `participant` and the matching `convo`. However, `filteredConvos` is not correctly rendered to reflect the newly filtered array.

I am new to Javascript, React, and Stack Overflow. My best assessment is that I am incorrectly passing my filtered array items back to `filteredConvos`, but I honestly don't have a enough experience to know.

Any assistance is deeply appreciated.

**Further context:**

- The data source I'm working with is a JSON file provided by
  google of an account's Hangouts chat.
- HangoutSearch.js:

```
    class HangoutSearch extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          searchTerm: ''
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      }

      handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({
          searchTerm: e.target.value
        });
      }

      render() {

        let filteredConvos = this.props.convos.filter((convo) => {
          return convo.conversation.conversation.participant_data.filter(
        (participant) => {
          return participant.fallback_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(
            this.state.searchTerm.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
        })
        })

        return(
          <div>
        <Form>
          <Form.Control
            placeholder='Enter the name of the chat participant'
            value={this.state.searchTerm}
            onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </Form>
        <HangoutList filteredConvos={filteredConvos}/>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default HangoutSearch;
```

- HangoutList.js

```
    class HangoutList extends Component {

      render() {
        return(
          <ListGroup>
            {this.props.filteredConvos.map((convo) => {
              return (
                <ListGroup.Item key={convo.conversation.conversation.id.id}>
                  {convo.conversation.conversation.participant_data.map(
                    (participant) => {
                      return (
                        <span key={participant.id.gaia_id}>
                          {participant.fallback_name}
                        </span>
                      )
                    }
                  )}
                </ListGroup.Item>
              )
            })}
          </ListGroup>
        );
      }
    }

    export default HangoutList;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "However, filteredConvos is not correctly rendered to reflect the newly filtered array."? Do you mean that `HangoutList` doesn't update?

Comment: @cbr Yes. The `HangoutList` component does not re-render the `filteredConvos` I've passed it. Would it help to see that component as well? However, I've placed a `console.log(filteredConvos)` after the filter block and `filteredConvos` remains unchanged. So I believe the problem arises before passing to the `HangoutList`.

Comment: Yes, do include it as well.

Comment: @cbr Updated! Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Ah, spotted it. The inner .filter which you use as the condition for the outer filter. It returns an array, which is truthy in JS. Try `.some` instead.

Comment: @cbr That worked perfectly!! Thank you so much. I hope one day I will understand this language to the depth and breadth that you do.

Comment: Oh nice! Allow me to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner `.filter` always returns an array, which are truthy in Javascript. You could use `.some` instead:

```
let filteredConvos = this.props.convos.filter((convo) => {
  return convo.conversation.conversation.participant_data.some((participant) => {
    return participant.fallback_name.toLowerCase().indexOf( this.state.searchTerm.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
  })
})
```